# Amazon S3 Signing Service for file uploads from browser (phonegap / desktop)

Tags: file-upload, amazon-s3

This question applies to both Desktop browsers as well as mobile apps using Phonegap / Cordova.

For uploads, the signature has to have the amazon secret encoded and hence created on the server for safety purposes. The alternative would be to generate the signature in the browser but that would mean exposing the Amazon Secret key.

Is there an alternative?

I found [apisigning.com](http://apisigning.com/), which forwards requests sent to them to the Amazon Advertising API.

Is there something similar for Amazon S3?